# sudo apt-get update is not working in Ubuntu after a fresh install

Tags: 12.10

Recently I install Ubuntu 12.10, after install, I am going to update Ubuntu, so  I open terminal, and write " sudo apt-get update " then more than 1 hour has spend it won't finished. Any suggestion ...

Answer (score 1):

All that

```
sudo apt-get update
```

does is to update the available archives.  It should download the changes which does nothing more than let Ubuntu know what updates are available.  If you want to then upgrade individual packages you should issue the command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and this will update any packages that are available except for when there is a change in dependencies. This would be the case when there is a kernel update available.  To perform the kernel update for 12.10 you would then have to issue the command

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Note that this will *not* upgrade the release level.  It does precisely the same thing as running the normal updates in the GUI.  A release upgrade done on the terminal is something completely different.

The apt-get update and upgrade commands should either run normally, or give you some error messages.  To get help fixing any problems you would have to tell us what those error messages are, but as far as I can tell the only problem is that you haven't actually run the upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your internet connection , I did a update while I was tethering with my phones 3G (No 4G in the area at the moment) and it took me a good 2 hours , It can spend alot of time or even a little with you have a stable fast connection

**NOTE - You are already running the latest version , That is the latest version of Ubuntu so your wasting some time there , Just check Ubuntu.com once a month to see if they have updated anything or use that terminal command once a month , Until now , You have the latest**

Comment: No, this command isn;t just about version numbers of Ubuntu. It's every package, that will most likely get changed between Ubuntu releases. If all it checked was one version number, it wouldn't be likely to take 2 hours.

Answer (score -1):

if you installed latest version of ubuntu i.e 12.10 , while installing it ask you

> download updates while installing
>   install the third party softwares

you just select these two options , then you install it done.
(ubuntu has not been released updates for ubuntu 12.10)